# jqgrid search options select group shows [object,object]...help....going nuts over this

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have been trying to get this working correctly for the past 2 days. Can someone help? I'm  about to pull my hair out, why doesn't it show the groups I have defined?

Being a new user I couldn't upload images here is the link to it though

[image]
these are my search options

```
{ //search settings
      closeOnEscape:true,
          modal:true,
          caption: "Search...",
          Find: "Search",
          Reset: "Clear",
          multipleSearch: true,
          overlay: 10,
          groupOps : [{ op: "AND", text: "AND" },   { op: "OR",  text: "OR" },{ op: "maybe",  text: "maybe" }],
          recreateFilter:true,
          onInitializeSearch: function ($form) {

           },
          afterRedraw: function () {

          }                                            
}
```

Comment: I suggest you post this question at jqgrid forum where you can find more help.. http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which error you has. How you can verify on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/customgroupop.htm) the code which you posted do work:

[image]

You can compare carefully your code with the code of the demo.

Comment: thanks oleg...seems like there is a js clash somewhere in  code...cause when i run the test code with my libraries it works fine but when i import it in my app it has the same issue

Comment: @user1699317: You are welcome! In any way you know now that the code which you posted is correct. You should have some problems in other parts of your JavaScript code (in your main application).